# Make every page 2 column-right in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I am working on TYPO3 and want to make every page 2 column-right layout. so please help me to remove second navigation from left side.

I commented the `navigationSecondLevelMenu < menu.secondlevel` from typoscript.

But it is not removed upto now.

Please help me

Comment: Your question is very laconic. Try to improve it if you expect sensible answer.

Comment: Try to clear the caches, and look into the template of the site - there is probably some markup you'd need to remove, too. Also, you'd probably need to remove/change some CSS. It all really depends on the setup your site is using, and how sophisticated the template is.

Comment: Ya I have to remove markup from template. But I did not know where markup is defined in default website. If u tell me path of template in default website then my problem can be easily solved.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can unset the lement aftewars with:

```
navigationSecondLevelMenu >
```

(`>` sign is comparable to PHP's `unset`) anyway if you won't give us more details, we won't try to guess your problem anymore.

Comment: Hey I am working on default typo3 website but dont want to show left menu means to say second level menu. Please help to how to remove second level menu from all pages. Where I have to edit so that second level will not appear in my website